# Objects in VBA frames

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new in vba and I have task to do. My MS.Frame frame1 has textboxes and comboboxes inside and I have frame2 created manually. I want to set the visibility attribute of frame2 if in combobox was set specific value. Should I set frame2 as new object?

```
Dim Ctrl As New FirstFrame
Dim CtrlFrameSecond As New SeondFrame

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set Ctrl.transactionFrameComboBox = Sheet2.Frame1.Controls.Item("transactionFrameComboBox")
    Set Ctrl.categoryComboBox = Sheet2.Frame1.Controls.Item("categoryComboBox")
End Sub
```

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents categoryComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Public WithEvents transactionFrameComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Public WithEvents countryFrameTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Public WithEvents Frame1 As MSForms.Frame
Public WithEvents Frame2 As MSForms.Frame
Public WithEvents controlledTransactionFrame As MSForms.Frame
Public WithEvents Sheet2 As Worksheet
Public WithEvents YesNoControlledTransactionComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox

Private Sub countryTextBox_Change()

    If countryTextBox.Value = "PL" Then
    controlledTransactionFrame.Visible //??
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please be more precise. What is `FirstFrame`  and `SeondFrame` these don't exist by default in VBA. Please check what a [mcve] is and provide a full example that is reproduceable. If you have set any references please include which.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As far as I know, `WithEvents` is not native in VBA, unless you use it on a custom class module. You'll need to be more precise to get some help.